# Magento 2 custom email template not including header

Tags: magento2, email, email-templates

When I load my custom template in `Marketing->Email Templates` and look at the preview the email looks fine and includes the header, but when I send an email using the custom template only the footer is included, the header and css styles are not included.

How the template header and footer are added:

```
<!--@subject My Subject  @-->
<!--@vars {
"var customer.email":"Customer Email",
"var customer.name":"Customer Name"
} @-->

{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}

template content

{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

Comment: are you sending email using which area?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had a slightly different problem but i think it would be good to post the solution here anyway as I came across this post when researching my issue.

I have a custom module that triggers an email on a cron. The header and footer were not being included when the emails were sent.

The header and email templates are only located in the frontend area. See : `public/vendor/magento/module-email/view/`

As such if your template options state 'adminhtml' or 'crontab' for example it wont find those templates.

In your custom code you will have a section or method containing something like this :

```
$this->transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier($templateId)
            ->setTemplateOptions($templateOptions)
            ->setTemplateVars($templateVars)
            ->addCc($ccs)
            ->setFrom($senderInfo)
            ->addTo($receiverInfo['email'], $receiverInfo['name']);
```

When you set your template options you need to make sure that you set the 'area' to be 'frontend' :

```
$templateOptions = array(
     'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
     'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,
);
```

Equally, if your email template is in adminhtml/templates/email/ it will have to be moved to frontend/templates/email/

** Just want to add that this works on a single store configuration. If you are using multi-store configuration. You will need to pull the store id via a different mechanism, like:

```
$order->getStoreId();
```

Comment: I am having same king of issue, I created one custom email template and i used custom theme for frontend. When I send email from custom module it was taking email of luma theme. I want it should take email template of my custom theme. After log debugging I found issue with store id

Comment: Yes, same issue getting in my email when use ADMINHTML area

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, It helped alot understanding the mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

Same here.

In my case, it comes from param `type` in email_templates.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
    <template id="my_custom_email_id" label="My custom email label" file="my_custom_email.html" type="html" module="Vendor_Module" area="frontend"/>
</config>
```

I change `type="text"` to `type="html"` and it works.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Add 2 variables as mentioned & it works :)

```
<!--@subject My Subject  @-->
<!--@vars {
"var customer.email":"Customer Email",
"var customer.name":"Customer Name",
"template config_path=\"design\/email\/footer_template\"":"Email Footer Template",
"template config_path=\"design\/email\/header_template\"":"Email Header Template"
} @-->

{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}

template content

{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

Comment: Hi Ankit, i have added above code but its not working for me ..

Comment: Not working for me too

Comment: Anyone get anywhere with this ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the correct store in the

```
 $templateOptions = array(
    'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
    'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,
    );
```